# Why i can not set image style height 100% for height as same as div container?

Tags: html, css

Why i can not set image style height 100% for height as same as div container ?

When i tried to test code it's will be show like this.

https://i.imgur.com/Q1MGP0Z.png

I want to show image like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT6ju.png

with class name `img_look` style `height: 100%;` How can i do ?

```css
.li_look{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    border-right: 3px solid #fff;
    margin-right: -3px;
    z-index: 11;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: #fff;
}
.div_1{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 197.207px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.a_tag{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.div_2{
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.img_look{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: unset;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li_look"> 
    <div class="div_1">
      <a href="#" class="a_tag">
        <div class="div_2">
          <img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.thisblogrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/man-and-bear-bath.jpg?resize=550%2C356" class="img_look">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use display: inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the parent container of the img tag. Since, there is no height defined for it, you cannot use 100% in relation to the parent container. Define a height as shown below in my code for .div_2. And it will work fine.

```css
.li_look{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    border-right: 3px solid #fff;
    margin-right: -3px;
    z-index: 11;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: #fff;
}
.div_1{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 197.207px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.a_tag{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.div_2{
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
}
.img_look{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: unset;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li_look"> 
    <div class="div_1">
      <a href="#" class="a_tag">
        <div class="div_2">
          <img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.thisblogrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/man-and-bear-bath.jpg?resize=550%2C356" class="img_look">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Neil If you noticed the code the asker has posted, it won't work the other way like you have mentioned. The problem lies within the .div2 dimension since it has not been fixed, the image will just take the actual dimensions of itself not the parent container and that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Your image IS the same size as your div, but your div ISN'T the same size as the `a` tag that hold it. since your `a` has `overflow:hidden;` you can't see that your div is actually bigger.

you cant just add `height:100%;` or `width:100%;` to your div, but keep your image dimensions the same.

Also : that feels really wrong don't you think ?

```
height: 197.207px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You Need This https://jsfiddle.net/wqhch5et/ view full screen mode.
You need to change  position: absolute; to   position: fixed; in div_2

```css
.li_look{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    border-right: 3px solid #fff;
    margin-right: -3px;
    z-index: 11;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: #fff;
}
.div_1{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 197.207px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.a_tag{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.div_2{
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}
.img_look{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: unset;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li_look"> 
    <div class="div_1">
      <a href="#" class="a_tag">
        <div class="div_2">
          <img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.thisblogrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/man-and-bear-bath.jpg?resize=550%2C356" class="img_look">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```